# How to handle IMAP requests from MSOutlook in ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, imap

**Brief**: I am tinkering with a personal project that would serve up Task objects to MSOutlook. I would like to create a new HTTP account in MSOutlook which points at my website's *.aspx page. This page would deliver a list of Task items that do not actually reside on a mail server but are instead stored in a XML file or other simple structure.

**Question**: Are there any guides for handling IMAP requests in ASP.NET? I've found plenty of information on developing a web client but I want something more akin to a server/service though nothing so robust.

**Background**: My daughter is in high school. She is computer literate but abhors complexity and all nerdiness. She is comfortable with MSOutlook so I would like to run a little website in my house to send homework Tasks to her. If I can set up an HTTP account, the Tasks will be delivered to her without any trouble on her part. Don't get me started on the screen scraping I'm doing to retrieve assignments from her teacher's "websites" (I don't think the term could be applied any more loosely without completely falling off).

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off using/customizing an Open Source IMAP server, there are several out here. But I am not sure if the mail server idea is a good one. You'd be bringing a lot of baggage into this effort.

Why don't you just send your daughter an email, as opposed to putting  the assignment on a web page and then trying to get it off of there?

If you must have the pull model (as opposed to a push model), why not put up an asp page with a "Send me the  assignment" button. She can go there, click on it, and will receive the content in the email.